# I get an error while trying to run a dynamic web project in jee

Tags: java

I keep getting this errors/warnings and i have no idea how to fix it, i am using wildfly 24.0 runtime server:

```
...
02:20:05,498 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
...
02:20:05,785 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file 'C:\Users\dell\Documents\2eme\JEE\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank.
02:20:05,808 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore C:\Users\dell\Documents\2eme\JEE\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
...
02:20:07,046 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class mvcModels.userService in Module "deployment.gotm-jee.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Failed to link mvcModels/userService (Module "deployment.gotm-jee.war" from Service Module Loader): mvcModels/userService has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:832)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

02:20:07,049 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class mvcModels.userService in Module "deployment.gotm-jee.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Failed to link mvcModels/userService (Module "deployment.gotm-jee.war" from Service Module Loader): mvcModels/userService has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:832)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

02:20:07,050 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."gotm-jee.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."gotm-jee.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "gotm-jee.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Failed to link mvcModels/userService (Module "deployment.gotm-jee.war" from Service Module Loader): mvcModels/userService has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:832)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more
...
```

I was running it as a normal dynamic web project and then i converted it to a maven project and added the java 7 dependency in my pom.xml file and that didn't fix it , i just  want to see if my .jsp code is working as intended or not, but in every project i've tried it's the same issue, did anybody run into this issue or know a fix for it ?

Answer (score -1):

from your log

> mvcModels/userService has been compiled by a more recent version of
> the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0),  this version of the Java
> Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

What means:

version 61 = jdk 17

version 52 = jdk 8

You probably need to change to jdk 17.